# How to populate listview from a class that has arraylist of string member?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating an app where there is a listview of apps activity, each app has an on click listener that opens an activity with app infotmation.

This is the Application class:

```
public class Application {

    private String title;
    private String imageUrl;
    private ArrayList<String> appVersions;


    public Application(String title, String imageUrl, ArrayList<String> appVersions) {
        this.title = imageName;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.appVersions = appVersions;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String imageName) {
        this.title = imageName;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAppVersions() {
        return appVersions;
    }

    public void setAppVersions(ArrayList<String> appVersions) {
        this.appVersions = appVersions;
    }
}
```

and this is the ApplicationVersionAdapter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ApplicationVersionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application> {

    private static final String TAG = "ApplicationVersionAdapt";
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;

    public ApplicationVersionAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Application> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String appVersion = getItem(position).getAppVersions().get(position);
        // String appVersion = getItem(position).getImageName();
        Log.d("Application version: ", getItem(position).getAppVersions().get(position));


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        TextView tvAppVersion = convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_version);
        tvAppVersion.setText(appVersion);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and in gallery activity I set the adapter:

```
ApplicationVersionAdapter adapter = new ApplicationVersionAdapter(this, 
R.layout.layout_appversion, list);
appVersionsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Each application object has versions:

Application 1:
name: app1
image: imageUrl
versions: v 1.0
          v 1.1
          v 1.2

Gallery layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_description"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Canada"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:id="@+id/app_versions">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

how to populate the list of application versions in the gallery activity?

**Update**
This is my RecyclerViewAdapter for the list of applications in main activity, I'm using images to fill the list not the application class but I will put the RecyclerViewAdapter to see the onClick listener:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImageNames, ArrayList<String> mImages) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);
        holder.title.setText(mImageNames.get(position));
        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + mImageNames.get(position));
                // Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GalleryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_name", mImageNames.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("image_url", mImages.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView title;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
Gallery activity:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryActivity";
    ListView appVersionsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        appVersionsList = findViewById(R.id.app_versions);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        getIncommingIntent();
    }

    private void getIncommingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getIncommingIntent: checking for the incomming intents");
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("image_url") && getIntent().hasExtra("image_name")) {
            String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
            String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");
            setImage(imageUrl, imageName);
        }
    }

    public void setImage(String imageUrl, String imageName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting the image and name to widgets.");

        TextView name = findViewById(R.id.image_description);
        name.setText(imageName);

        ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(image);
}
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: I can populate the list of applications from main activity, but I want to populate the application version list in gallery activity when you click on application list item

Comment: You have to explain the problem. What you have done so far and What you are trying to do.

Comment: So far I made an adapter to populate the list of applications (main activity) and sent the name of application list item when you click on it to an activity that shows information about the app (gallery activity) like app image, app title, app versions (array list of string)
I want to populate the application versions list in the gallery activity

Comment: Populate another list  with app version list like you create a list of application.

Comment: You mean create another adapter for the application list and populate the list in gallery activity?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Check out my update

Comment: Post your Gallery Activity Code

Answer (score 0):

In you app ClickListener :

```
ArrayList<String> versionList = adapter.getItem(position).getAppVersions();
```

and use `versionList` in `ApplicationVersionAdapter`

```
ApplicationVersionAdapter adapter = new ApplicationVersionAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_appversion, versionList);
appVersionsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As you are creating another list for app version so your `Adapter` need List of String (as your data structure).

Change your `ApplicationVersionAdapter`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ApplicationVersionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private static final String TAG = "ApplicationVersionAdapt";
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;

public ApplicationVersionAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    String appVersion = getItem(position);
    // String appVersion = getItem(position).getImageName();
    Log.d("Application version: ", getItem(position));


    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
    TextView tvAppVersion = convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_version);
    tvAppVersion.setText(appVersion);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

In `ApplicationVersionAdapter` you are going to List of Application again in `getView` thats wrong. You have to only care about a specific Application List of version.